# autoexp.dat does not seem to take affect in Visual Studio C++ 2005 debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

autoexp.dat does not seem to take affect in Visual Studio C++ 2005 debugger.
I am not trying to add any custom rules. Just want commonly used stuff like stl::string, to display in a friendlier manner.
Does anyone know. how I can accomplish this? Is this just question of specifying  a path to the autoexp.dat file somewhere. The file is available under the Visual Studio installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in 2008, with the debugger showing only the e.g. std::vector _Myfirst, 
_Mylast members rather than the vector size and children.

Open Tools/Options/Debugging/General and clear the flag "Show raw structure of objects in variable windows"

(Presumably the suggest

Answer (score 0):

This got me the closest.
http://garrys-brain.blogspot.com/2007/12/stlport-visual-studio-2005-visualisers.html

It would appear you need to make adjustments for types while using ports.
Also you might have to make changes to the display to display exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may have to do with the infamous VirtualStore in Windows Vista/7. I could change this in XP but when I try to update the autoexp.dat file in Win7 it creates a copy in AppData\Local\VirtualStore.... instead. I assume that the studio does read the original file when starting, so my changes are not seen. If anyone knows how to be able to edit the actual file please tell me how!